# MySQL - Do I need a nested query?

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query that displays, for each activity, a count of the number of males and number of females.

Preferably in a 3 column format, activity_name, male (computed column), female (computed column).

I think I may need to use nested queries, but I cannot figure out how. Or could this be done by just using GROUP BY?

My tables are:

**Child**
child_id
child_fname
child_sname
child_gender
etc etc

**Activity**
activity_id
activity_name
etc etc

**Child_Activity_Item**
child_id
activity_id

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  a.activity_id,
  a.activity_name,
  COUNT(IF(c.child_gender = 'M', c.child_gender, NULL)) male,
  COUNT(IF(c.child_gender = 'F', c.child_gender, NULL)) female
FROM
  Activity a
  JOIN Child_Activity_Item ca
    ON ca.activity_id = a.activity_id
  JOIN Child c
    ON c.child_id = ca.child_id
GROUP BY a.activity_id
```

Comment: Thank you, can I ask if there is a difference between using JOIN and WHERE? As I have not been taught JOIN on my degree course, it is new to me!

Comment: In this case you may use 'FROM table1, table2, table3' with WHERE condition, the result will be the same. I only prefere to use JOIN clauses.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  MaleList.Activity_Name,
        MaleList.totalMale,
        FemaleList.totalFemale,
FROM
(
    SELECT  a.Activity_ID, 
            a.Activity_Name,
            COUNT(c.child_gender) totalMale
    FROM    Activity a 
                INNER JOIN Child_Activity_Item b
                    on a.activity_id = b.activity_ID
                INNER JOIN Child c
                    on b.child_id =  c.child_id
    WHERE   c.child_gender = 'male'
    Group BY a.Activity_ID
) as MaleList INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  a.Activity_ID, 
            a.Activity_Name,
            COUNT(c.child_gender) totalFemale
    FROM    Activity a 
                INNER JOIN Child_Activity_Item b
                    on a.activity_id = b.activity_ID
                INNER JOIN Child c
                    on b.child_id =  c.child_id
    WHERE   c.child_gender = 'female'
    Group BY a.Activity_ID
) as FemaleList 
    ON  MaleList.Activity_ID =  FemaleList.Activity_ID
```

you cannot directly get a three-column result because there is only only column that holds the gender.